# Sort column of similar text alphabetically by part of text, not first different letter. Sort column based on another with Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

Here is an example of what I am attempting to sort from A to Z:

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.uniqueActivity}" drawable="charlie"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.otherActivity}" drawable="alpha"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.differentActivity}" drawable="beta"/>
```

I want to keep the same structure of each line, but sort the lines A to Z as "alpha", "beta", "charlie" (not by "differentActivity", "otherActivity", "uniqueActivity").

I have tried going about this by extracting the text into another column using the formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("drawable=",A1))
```

But this route does not keep "uniqueActivity" partnered with "charlie" when the sorted column is pasted back. There must be an easier way of accomplishing this with only the sort function.

Perhaps we can choose which part of the text to sort by if it comes after "drawable="?

Comment: "...when the sorted column is pasted back" this line confuses me. Why are you pasting what you extract elsewhere? Why don't you just insert a intermediary column, apply your formula to extract "charlie", "alpha" and "beta" and then sort your whole table based on that column? When you do a sort you don't just apply the sort to 1 column, but rather apply it to the whole table based on that 1 column. Is this maybe where your error is?

Comment: @nbayly That was just one attempt I made at solving my problem because I was unsure of how to sort one column based on the other. Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: Easiest way is to create the column as we discussed the select your whole table (including headers) and press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `L` or selecting `Filter` option on the `DATA` Ribbon section. Then clicking the header in your inserted column you can select to sort and it will sort the whole table based on that column. Regards.

Comment: @nbayly Beautiful, this worked perfectly. If you would like to copy your last comment into an answer I'll select it as the best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create intermediary column next to your data to extract your sorting values and apply Auto Filter to the whole table. You can apply Auto Filter selecting your whole table (including headers) and pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `L` or selecting Filter option on the `DATA` Ribbon section. Then clicking the header in your inserted column you can select to sort and it will sort the whole table based on that column. Regards.